# Which Eyeshot entity is more efficient?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, cad, eyeshot

I am using the WPF Control Eyeshot (http://www.devdept.com/) to build an application where I handle multiple 3D entities, but **I do not perform boolean operations between them**.

Eyeshot offers me the following options for entities of this sort (cylinders, spheres, cubes, etc): Mesh, Solid, Surface or Solid3D.

I am confused on which one of these should I use, as they all suffice my needs.

Which one is more efficient in memory consumption and performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mesh, definitely. Possibly with `Mesh.LightWeight = true`. This is the most cheap 3D object representation inside Eyeshot. It relies only on `Mesh.Vertices` and `Mesh.Triangles` arrays.

Comment: Thank you! One question though: how would you do it in Eyeshot Standard, which doesn't allow for Mesh Type?

Comment: Within the eyeshot libraries there is a Mesh datatype. This is the "Mesh" you should use.  You might be referencing the wrong library.